# SearchView Focus on Samsung Galaxy Tab (Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, keyboard, focus, samsung-mobile, searchview

Currently i'm encountering a strange problem with the SearchView in the ActionBar on especially Samsung Galaxy Tab Devices.

The app has a standard ActionBar (not Sherlock) and displays a SearchView. This View is intended to be visible at all time. And that also works perfectly.

The problem appears after the Dismissing the Soft-Keyboard in the SearchView. On Nexus (4.4) or Asus Devices (4.0) the SearchView looses Focus. On the Galaxy Tab this does not happen.

If you set a listener to the SearchView with "setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener" it is only called when it requests the focus. But not, when the user dismisses the Keyboard. (This also only is so on these Galaxy Stuff). When using "clearFocus()" programmatically both events are shown and fired.

These behavior makes using the app really terribly:
1) Enter some text into SearchView
2) Dismiss Keyboard
3) Open menu from the action bar (...)
4) Dismiss menu without selecting an entry
=> Keyboard slides up and SearchView is focused

Any ideas? We don't want to write our own implementation of things, which should be Android core.

Here's an image where you can clearly see, that the SearchView still has Focus after the user dismissed the keyboard.

[image: After Keyboard Dismissed by User]

I created some small demo app which could help you to understand what i did.

MainActivity
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
protected static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private SearchView mSearchView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search something");
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Focus is: " + hasFocus);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Focus is: " + hasFocus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_browse:
        //Just find out how focus changes if another activity is launched
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        return true;
    case R.id.action_setFocus:
        if (mSearchView != null) {
            mSearchView.requestFocus();
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.action_clearFocus:
        if (mSearchView != null) {
            mSearchView.clearFocus();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        if (mSearchView != null) {
            mSearchView.clearFocus();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/testEditText"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hello_world">
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

main.xml (Menu)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_browse"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Browse"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_setFocus"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Set Focus"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_clearFocus"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Clear Focus"/>

</menu>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.searchviewtest.MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
searchView.clearFocus();
View focused = searchView.getFocusedChild();
if (focused != null) {
    focused.clearFocus();
}
```

where `item` is the menu item you clicked on